# Increase Screenshot Size (Resolution)?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

I sometimes use the screenshot feature copied to clipboard to paste it quickly when I need it. I usually use that in Mail, however I always realize that the picture sent is really small in size (resolution). If a screenshot is taken at a resolution of 800x600, it is scaled down to 300x100 or something similar (just a rough example).

Is there a way I can keep the resolution of screenshots copied to clipboard 'exact' ? And prevent them from being scaled down ?

Comment: Perhaps it is the thumbnail you see that is scaled down and not the actual picture?

Comment: Nope the actual picture is actually smaller than it should be. Maybe it is a Mail feature ? not sure.

Comment: how you do screenshot? command+shift+3?